R Shiny; how to log all output observed in console to a logfile
on reflection; I suspect that this issue is entirely a result of limitations of the fundamental base::sink ; which does not support split=TRUE when type="message" - cannot split the message connection
that aside; I find it mysterious that sink(file = flog, type = "message") resulted in seeing the trace in the console but not in the flog rather than the reverse.

Over a year ago I raised a query/feature request on this topic to the offical forum;
but got no traction with it.
Perhaps the wonderful stackoverflow community have ideas ?
https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3677
p.s. similarly, a year ago I posted the issue the the community forum; however, while there was suggestions regarding calling the app as a wrapped process; I desire a way to be more direct and avoid such wrapping (as it would cause me other challenges).
https://forum.posit.co/t/shiny-devmode-and-writing-logs-sink/143106

I would like to understand a best practice way to log a shiny app, so as to track the console, which will also include shiny error traces from shiny::devmode. If this is not currently possible, I would request this as a feature.
Here is a reprex to illustrate the issue:
library(shiny)
shiny::devmode()
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("simple", "Just to add something normal to the log"),
  actionButton("force_error_button", "Force an Error")
)
close_sink_and_quit <- function(){
  sink(file = NULL,type = "message") 
  sink(file = NULL,type = "output") 
  close(con = flog)
  stopApp()
}

options(error = close_sink_and_quit)
options(shiny.error = close_sink_and_quit)


flog <- file("my_shiny_log", open = "wt")
sink(file = flog, split = TRUE)
sink(file = flog, type = "message")

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  onStop(function() {cat("Session stopped\n") ;close_sink_and_quit()})
  

  observeEvent(input$simple,
               cat("\npressed for",input$simple))

  
  observeEvent(input$force_error_button, {
    stop(paste("Error Forced at ", Sys.time()))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
if I refrain from pressing my force error button, but hit the simple button a few times,
I happily get the corresponding message in my console, as well as in "my_shiny_log" file .
if I force an error, although I see a useful stack trace in the console, this is not represented in the "my_shiny_log" file.
I've been pulling my hair out on this point :D
example of trace that shows in console but not in the sink log file :
Warning: Error in <observer:observeEvent(input$force_error_button)>: Error Forced at  2022-07-26 12:43:12
  76: h
  75: .handleSimpleError
  74: stop
  73: <observer:observeEvent(input$force_error_button)> [#11]
  72: valueFunc
  71: ..stacktraceon..
  70: contextFunc

so to summarise, is it possible to duplicate the full console including devmode's stacktrace in a sinked logging file?, or would this require a new devmode feature/bugfix to achieve ?
I had it suggested to me that a combination of wrapping the app inside a callr/processx might be a way to go, though this seemed rather heavyweight to me... thoughts ?
I tried to get a complete log, but only got a partial log

using callr/processx is the easiest [and seemingly the only complete] solution to your problem currently.
